# Solr query: someValue:[columnName1 TO columnName2]

Tags: solr

From the documentation:

`age:[18 TO 30]`

What if I wanted to do instead:

`16:[CanDrinkMinimumAge TO CanDrinkMaximumAge]`

Where `CanDrinkMinimumAge` is a Solr field (let's say that we're talking country records) and 16 is the variable part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to query the fields separately:

```
fq=CanDrinkMinimumAge:[* TO 16] AND CanDrinkMaximumAge:[16 TO *] AND
```

This will get you any documents where `CanDrinkMinimumAge` is at 16 or lower, and where the `CanDrinkMaximumAge` is at least 16.